# Please confirm my try to read The following multiplicities for the associations

Tags: uml

[image]

1- zero or many objects of type`Person` should be associated to each

object of type `Company`

2- zero or many objects of type`Company` should be associated to

each object of type `Person`

---

3-zero or one object of type`Woman` should be associated to each

object of type `Man`

4-zero or one object of type `Man` should be associated to each object

of type`Woman`

---

5- one object of type `Person` should be associated to each object of

type `Car`

6-zero or many objects of type `Car` should be associated to each

object of type `Person`

---

7-zero or one object of type `line` should be associated to each object

of type `Point`

8-two objects of type `Point` should be associated to each object of

type `Line`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your readings are all correct.  A couple of observations/suggestions:

You can write the text phrases a little more concisely as follows:

```
Each Person is associated with zero or more Company(ies)
....
Each Car is associated with exactly one Person
....
```

(Note use of plural 'Companies' - reads better)

It really helps if you add verb phrases to describe the meaning of the relationship instead of just using 'is associated with'.

```
Each Person is employed by zero or more Companies
Each Company employs zero or more People
....
Each Car is owned by exactly one Person
Each Person owns zero or more Cars
....
```

hth